# How to create multiple producers, each producer for different Kafka server using KafkaTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Suppose I have three Kafka servers(Independent from each other) and I have one publishing entity, I want to publish events to these three Kafka servers Independently. That's why I want to create three producers. I want to ask, is there any way to create producers using KafkaTemplate, so I will be able to publish independently?

Comment: What sort of workaround have you tried?

Comment: One is to directly create the producer and in properties providing only the one server as bootstrap-server. But this way we will not get the benefits of Kafkatemplate. @surajs1n

Comment: Why not post to 3 different topics instead of having three different kafka instances?

Comment: @Omtara My use case is:- I have three main application instances running on three different servers, each instance having its own independent Kafka server. Now I will be having three Kafka servers with the same topics. Now I have some independent entity from where I want to publish to these Kafka servers independently.

Comment: @VakulGupta Have you got any success on it. Please let me know if there is any way